# Blackberry Web emulator

Tags: blackberry, emulation, blackberry-simulator

I am looking for a blackberry emulator to run web apps. I looked at the StackOverflow question "[Is there a Blackberry Browser emulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4856642/is-there-a-blackberry-browser-emulator)" but those emulators are error filled and cannot access mobile web.

Are there any other good emulators out there?

Comment: They work well and they can access mobile web. You need install an MDS server.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a Blackberry Browser emulator?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4856642/is-there-a-blackberry-browser-emulator)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to this post to make your simulator work

[Blackberry MDS simulator - Can't connect to the internet in the simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2653701/blackberry-mds-simulator-cant-connect-to-the-internet-in-the-simulator)

or you can use chrome plugin : https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/geelfhphabnejjhdalkjhgipohgpdnoc

Comment: Much better! Thanks for the help.